# Camel: Is it possible to Scheduler Daily Task using Timer Component at given time?

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, timertask

We use Quartz for same purpose.

I cam across Timer Component but not able to find any code which fire Timer at given time but Timer continuously poll. Like i want timer to execute 12:10 daily.

Following example i got but same is not helpful in job scheduling:

```java
Date future = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String time = sdf.format(future);

fromF("timer://simpleTimer?time=%s&pattern=dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", time)
  .setBody(simple("Hello from timer at ${header.firedTime}"))
  .to("stream:out");
```

Can you help me how to configure timer for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `time` attribute to 12:10, `fixedRate` to `true` and `period` to 1 day (see [Timer component propeties](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/timer-component.html)).

Also, if you're using Camel 3.x, my recommendation is to use type-safe Endpoint DSL, it'd help avoiding misconfiguration errors. Example:

URI-string endpoint

```java
from("timer:click?period=3000&fixedRate=true")
    .to("seda:foo?blockWhenFull=true");
```

Endpoint DSL

```java
from(timer("click").period(3000).fixedRate(true))
    .to(seda("foo").blockWhenFull(true));
```